# Can I force the full speed of the indexing service in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-search

The solution detailed in this [prior question](https://superuser.com/questions/234211/can-i-force-full-speed-to-the-indexing-service-of-windows) does not appear to work in windows 10, because the registry items listed do not exist. Is there any way to do this in windows 10?

Comment: Maybe it has moved, have you tried doing a search for `DisableBackoff` in the registry?

Comment: I was able to find the registry item without a problem in Windows 10.  The group policy still exists.

Comment: In many cases, the registry key is not pre-existing, but that does not mean they don't work.  You can simply create new keys and new values matching what is listed and they work.  Some times a reboot required.